# Remover borda que separa as colunas de uma tabela

Tags: html, css, table

Boa noite! Estou tentando remover a borda que separa as colunas de uma tabela, mas não funciona.

A Tabela é essa:

```
<table border="0">
<td>
    <tr>
        <img src="http://depositodetudo.pe.hu/hospedagem3/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/fisk-logo.png" width="150" height="150"align="left">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <p>
            <center><b>FISK CENTRO DE ENSINO</b><br></center>
            130% nos cursos de inglês e espanhol.<br>
            Endereço: Av. Vale do Rio Pimenta, quadra 01, nº. 09 - Olho D'água<br>
            Telefone: 3248-1891<br>
            contato@fisksaoluis.com.br<br>
        </p>
    </tr>
</td>
```

O css que estou usando é esse, pois não consegui achar uma propriedade pra remover só o que quero...

```
table, tr, td {
border: 0px; 
}
```

[image: A parte que tento remover está no círculo vermelho]

A parte que tento remover está no círculo vermelho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, precisa consertar seu HTML, pois você está pondo `tr` dentro de `td`, fechando coisa que não abriu, e outros probleminhas.

Uma vez resolvido o código, vamos às bordas:

Se for HTML5, use CSS:

```
table {background:white;border:1px solid gray}
td {border:none}
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/yVXNOW)**.

Se for HTML4 (pra mail marketing, etc):

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" rules="none">
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/RogPoj)**.

Vale também uma olhada nestas propriedades CSS se precisar de bordas nas células em outras ocasiões:

```
border-spacing: 2px;
border-collapse: collapse;
```

Suponho que você esteja fazendo algo como *mail marketing*. Se for um *layout* de página, CSS seria o mais indicado no lugar da tabela. Seria o caso de dar uma estudada em CSS e refazer sem tabela.

Answer (score 1):

Sem o código completo não tem como eu afirmar que funcione, mas você pode usar o `border: none;` ou com o `border-left: none;` na `td` que você quer.

Answer (score -2):

Utilizando CSS:

```css
table{
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
```